# Selenium validating date

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium

I want to know how to do this in Selenium, I have a calendar, now what I wanted to is when I click a link it should display the week range like for example when I click March 25 it should display March 25 - March 31, 2013. I don't know how to this with Selenium I am looking for the Xpath of it but I don't know how to deal with it in Selenium

This is the example xPath of the clicked cell:

```
//*[@id='weeker']/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td
```

BTW I am testing this with C#

Thanks

Comment: This isn't clear. So you've got a calendar. Great. Is it a RadCalendar or a fancy framework like that, or is it a jQuery plugin etc? Ok, so you click the link on this calendar. Then what? Are you having trouble clicking it in the first place?

Comment: Yeah similar to that. Am sorry if my question is kinda vague.

Comment: I think I know what omar means..he just wants to click the specific date from a calendar using Selenium..Well a good way to do this is instead of trying to click to the XPATH, try using send keys (tab, enter, or numbers)..ie after selecting the calendar typeing 2, 5 should get you to the 25th of the month..if you were at ruby I will show an example as well, but I think you should look at the win32ole send keys first..